# SecurityException en administrador de dispositivos Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de Android que utiliza la administración del dispositivo para cambiar la contraseña del teléfono.

Como muchos saben el administrador de dispositivos quedo obsoleto y solo funcionan algunos metodos como devicePolicyManager.lockNow(); pero si intento cambiar la contraseña del dispositivo como por ejemplo devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("", 0);

Me lanzara un SecurityException, posiblemente por estar obsoleto el administrador de dispositivos.

Recibo el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
```

Registré la politica necesaria, existe otra manera de resetear con resetPasswordWithToken() pero no se si funcione, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de saltarse el SecurityException editando alguna clase interna, o podria alguien explicarme como funciona.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        ...
        <reset-password/>
        ...
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: *"quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de saltarse el SecurityException editando alguna clase interna"* -> Si existiese sería un gran motivo para no usar Android

Comment: Excelente, podrias decirme como funciona o en donde encontrar informacion al respecto? Por ejemplo si intento usar el metodo devicePolicyManager.setDeviceOwnerLockScreenInfo(); me lanzara el SecurityException como es el mecanismo, que hace que funcione con lockNow() pero no con setDeviceOwnerLockScreenInfo() y disculpa la ignorancia. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score -1):

Al ver el mensaje de error puedes deducir que es un problema relacionado a seguridad/permisos, en este caso el método resetPassword(password, flag) de la clase devicePolicyManager es obsoleta desde Android 11.

Ahora debes usar el método [resetPasswordWithToken()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#resetPasswordWithToken(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int))

> [resetPasswordWithToken()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#resetPasswordWithToken(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int)) A diferencia de `resetPassword(String, int)`, esta API puede cambiar la
> contraseña incluso antes de que el usuario o el dispositivo se
> desbloquee o descifre. El token proporcionado debe haberse
> aprovisionado previamente a través de
> `setResetPasswordToken(ComponentName, byte)` y estar en estado activo
> `isResetPasswordTokenActive(ComponentName)`.

Este es un ejemplo usando ahora `resetPasswordWithToken()` :

```
private void changePassword() {
    byte[] token = generateRandomPasswordToken();
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
    if (devicePolicyManager != null) {
        devicePolicyManager.setResetPasswordToken(MyAdmin.getComponentName(this), token);
        devicePolicyManager.resetPasswordWithToken(MyAdmin.getComponentName(this), "9876", token, 0);
    }
}

private byte[] generateRandomPasswordToken() {
    try {
        return SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").generateSeed(32);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```